# Is there a shorter way to prove this sum inequality?

Tags: calculus, inequality, summation

Here's a problem that caught my interest:

> Let $a_1,\cdot\cdot\cdot,a_n$ and $b_1,\cdot\cdot\cdot,b_n$ be arbitrary real numbers and $c_1,\cdot\cdot\cdot,c_n$ be positive real numbers. Prove that $$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\dfrac{a_ia_j}{c_i+c_j}\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\dfrac{b_ib_j}{c_i+c_j}\right)\geq \left(\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\dfrac{a_ib_j}{c_i+c_j}\right)^2$$

My proof for this problem is quite lengthy in my opinion and I'm wondering if there's a shorter way to prove it. Here's my proof:

We can assume that not all $a_i$ and $b_j$ are equal to $0$. First, we prove that $$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\dfrac{a_ia_j}{c_i+c_j}x^{c_i+c_j}\geq 0, \ x\geq 0$$ We have $$xf'(x)=\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_ix^{c_i}\right)^2\geq 0$$ and therefore $f(x)\geq f(0)=0$ for $x\geq 0$. Similarly, $$g(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\dfrac{b_ib_j}{c_i+c_j}x^{c_i+c_j}\geq 0, \ x\geq 0$$ We now denote $$h(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\dfrac{a_ib_j}{c_i+c_j}x^{c_i+c_j}$$ We want to show that $f(x)g(x)\geq h^2(x)$ for $x\geq 0$. To this end, we can assume that $h(x)\geq 0$ for the given values of $x$, otherwise we'll have to change $a_i$ with $-a_i$. Therefore, we need to show that $s(x)=\sqrt{f(x)}\sqrt{g(x)}-f(x)\geq 0$. Since $a^2+b^2\geq 2ab$ and $x\geq 0$, we obtain $$xs'(x)=\dfrac{xf'(x)\sqrt{g(x)}}{2\sqrt{f(x)}}+\dfrac{xg'(x)\sqrt{f(x)}}{2\sqrt{g(x)}}-xh'(x)\geq\sqrt{xf'(x)xg'(x)}-xh'(x)$$
Note that $$\sqrt{xf'(x)xg'(x)}-xh'(x)=\left|\sum_{i=1}^na_ix^{c_i}\sum_{i=1}^nb_ix^{c_i}\right|-\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n a_ib_jx^{c_i+c_j}\geq \sum_{i=1}^na_ix^{c_i}\sum_{i=1}^nb_ix^{c_i}-\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n a_ib_jx^{c_i+c_j}$$
and since the RHS of the inequality above is equal to $0$, we have that $s(x)>s(0)$ for $x\ne 0$.

I feel like there's an inequality I'm not seeing that could prove the statement quickly. Any ideas?

Comment: It is a version of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the inner product
$$\langle P,Q\rangle =\int\limits_0^1P(x)Q(x)\,dx$$ Then for  $P(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ix^{c_i-1/2}$ and $Q(x)=\sum_{j=1}^{n}b_jx^{c_j-1/2}$ we get $$\langle P,Q\rangle =\sum_{i,j=1}^n{a_ib_j\over c_i+c_j}$$ The desired inequality coincides with the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $$\langle P,Q\rangle ^2 \le \langle P,P\rangle 
\langle Q,Q\rangle $$

Comment: Interesting. Thanks.